# Nice corollaries to Poincaré-Bendixson theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am interested in applications of Poincaré-Bendixson theorem not (explicitely) related to ODEs.

Let $X \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$,  $(t_0,x_0) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2$ and $x \in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2)$ a solution to the IVP $\begin{cases}x'=X(x) \\ x(t_0)=x_0\end{cases}$

The **$\omega$-limit** of $x_0$ (or of $x$) is $\omega(x_0)=\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \exists (t_n) \ \text{such that} \ t_n \to + \infty, \ x(t_n)\to y \}$.

> **Theorem (Poincaré-Bendixson)**
>
> If $\omega(x_0)$ is nonempty, compact and does not contain any zero of $X$, then $\omega(x_0)$ is a periodic orbit.

Some consequences:

> **Theorem ($C^1$-version of Brouwer's fixed point theorem in dimension two)**
>
> Let $f : \overline{D} \to \overline{D}$ be a $C^1$ function from the closed unit disk to itself. Then $f$ has a fixed point.
>
> **Theorem ($C^1$-version of the hairy ball theorem in dimension two)**
>
> A $C^1$-vector field on $\mathbb{S}^2$ has a zero.

Do you know other consequences of Poincaré-Bendixson theorem not related to differential equations? For example, can the fundamental theorem of algebra be proved like that?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing how to get to Hairy Ball Theorem from Poincare Bendixson. Do you have a reference ?

Comment: @nonlinearism: I have no reference, but just notice that the proof of Poincaré-Bendixson theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be adapted on $\mathbb{S}^2$; then, by compacity of $\mathbb{S}^2$, any $\omega$-limit is nonempty, so an $\omega$-limit either contains a zero or is a periodic orbit. However, the domain bounded by a periodic orbit contains necessary a zero.

Comment: @Seirios I'm also interested in applications of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem that have nothing to do with ODE. Did you find some more or do you have a reference where I can find them? Please... It would be very useful for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I answer my second question, proving the fundamental theorem of algebra from Poincaré-Bendixson theorem:

Suppose by contradiction that there exists a polynomial $P \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $P(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Then the function $z \mapsto 1/P(z)$ defines a vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Clearly, there exists $R>0$ such that $$\frac{1}{|P(z)|} < |z| \ \ \text{for all} \ |z|=R.$$

Therefore, if $B$ denotes the closed ball of radius $R$ centered at $0$, $X$ is defined on $B$ and points inward on $\partial B$: $B$ is stable under the flow of $X$. Finally, it is sufficient to apply Poincaré-Bendixson theorem to find a limit cycle (by compactness, an $\omega$-limit cannot be empty); but a limit cycle (as a Jordan curve) always contains a fixed point (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320419/36434)), a contradiction (clearly, $X$ is a non-vanishing vector field).

Comment: How it is true that all vectors on $\partial B$ is pointing inwards??

Comment: As mentioned, because $B$ is stable under the flow of $X$. If some vector on $\partial B$ is pointing outward, then the corresponding point would be sent outside $B$ by the flow.

Comment: The reasoning does not seem correct. The first question above still stands.